# How can I add a custom property with a dynamically defined name to an object?

Tags: python, custom-properties

This works great:

```
bpy.types.Object.color_asd = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
                subtype='COLOR',
            )
```

This errors:

```
UID_short = "asd"
bpy.types.Object[f"color_{UID_short}"] = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
                subtype='COLOR',
            )
```

Error:

```
TypeError: 'bpy_struct_meta_idprop' object does not support item assignment
```

But the approach is wrong to begin with.
Let's say I have 2 cubes, Cube and Cube.001
I then would like to create a custom property only for a specific object like:
Cube.color_asd

And for Cube.001 for example
Cube.001.color_mega

Like so:

```
name = f"color_{UID_short}"
obj[name] = bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(
            subtype='COLOR',
        )
```

Which then errors with:

```
Error: Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\bratp\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\3.6\scripts\addons\Liebherr-Toolbox\material_panel.py", line 1037, in execute
    obj[name] = bpy.props.PointerProperty(type = ObjectCustomColors)
TypeError: invalid id-property type _PropertyDeferred not supported
```

I can't figure either issue out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionary accessors are for interface-level attributes, not for API-defined ones. You can define them with python but for all intents and purposes they're the same as if you created them using the interface.

`bpy.data.objects["Cube"]["my_prop"] = 2`

[image]

If you want to add an API-defined property to all `bpy.types.Object` constructs, you need to use [setattr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#setattr).

```
UID_short = "asd"
setattr(bpy.types.Object, f"color_{UID_short}", bpy.props.FloatVectorProperty(subtype="COLOR"))
```

[image]

If you want to add a color type interface custom property, you can use [bpy.types.Struct.id_properties_ui](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bpy.types.bpy_struct.html#bpy.types.bpy_struct.id_properties_ui).

```
import bpy

UID_short = "asd"
name = f"color_{UID_short}"

bpy.data.objects["Cube"][name] = (1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0)
ui_prop = bpy.data.objects["Cube"].id_properties_ui(name)
ui_prop.update(subtype="COLOR", min=0, max=1)
```

[image]

Comment: I went for the struct.id approach as I want an object pacific approach.
It works perfectly.
I did have difficulties adding it to the actual UI panel, so I wanted to post this in case someone stumbles upon it.
The additional " required was quite unintuitive. 
`
    color_node_name = f"color_{UID_Short}"
            if helpers.Has_Material_Attribute_Node(material, color_node_name):
                    layout.prop(obj, f'["{color_node_name}"]', text = UID_Short)
`